# Bootstrap Rowspan Alignment

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to align my elements on my site like on the picture I attached.
I want to achieve something like you can do with col and `row-span` with tables in `HTML`.
I'm using `bootstrap 4`.
I tried to make it in the same row but it won't fit in the 12 cols that bootstrap allows, also it can't fit because of the carousel.
I'm a beginner and I can't find the solution.
Thanks for the help.

Images:

[Current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFf2a.jpg)

[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAjGG.jpg)

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container-fluid"> 
                <div class="row"> <!-- Welcome text  -->
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <p class="h1 text-center p-2">Üdvözöljük Városunk weboldalán!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="row"> <!--First row-->
                
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 p-1"> <!-- Slider -->
                        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 
                          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                          </ol>
                          <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                              <img class="d-block " src="public/IMG/center/kozpont_1.jpg" alt="First slide">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                              <img class="d-block " src="public/IMG/strand/strand_1.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                              <img class="d-block " src="public/IMG/strand/strand_3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Előző</span>
                          </a>
                          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Következő</span>
                          </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 p-1"> <!-- Turizmus -->
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;"> 
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Turizmus</h5>
                            <ul class="list-group ">
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">Eseménynaptár</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">Elhelyezkedés</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">Látnivalók, nevezetességek</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">Strandfürdő</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">Szálláshelyek</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 p-1"> <!-- Gyorslinkek -->
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;"> 
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Gyorslinkek</h5>
                            <ul class="list-group ">
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">A Polgármesteri Hivatal ügyfélfogadása</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">Rendelettár</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">Képviselő-testület</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">A Jász-Nagykun-Szolnok Megyei Kormányhivatal Járási Hivatala</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">Háziorvosok, fogorvosok rendelési ideje</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 p-1"> <!-- Hírdetmények -->
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;"> 
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Hirdetmények</h5>
                            <ul class="list-group ">
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">Térfigyelő rendszer</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">WIFI pontok</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">Beruházások</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">Pályázatok</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">Közérdekű információk</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div> <!-- End of first row-->
                
                <div class="row"><!--Second row-->
                
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 p-1"> <!-- Hírdetmények -->
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;"> 
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Hirdetmények</h5>
                            <ul class="list-group ">
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">Térfigyelő rendszer</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">WIFI pontok</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">Beruházások</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">Pályázatok</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="card-link">Közérdekű információk</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div><!-- End of second row-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>

  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' integrity='sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl' crossorigin='anonymous'>

</head>

<body>

  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
      <!-- Welcome text  -->
      <div class='col-lg-12'>
        <p class='h1 text-center p-2'>Üdvözöljük Városunk weboldalán!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='row'>
      <!--First row-->

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 p-1">
        <!-- Slider -->
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block " src="public/IMG/center/kozpont_1.jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block " src="public/IMG/strand/strand_1.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block " src="public/IMG/strand/strand_3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Előző</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Következő</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='col-lg-2 col-md-4 p-1'>
        <!-- Turizmus -->
        <div class='card' style='width: 18rem;'>
          <div class='card-body'>
            <h5 class='card-title'>Turizmus</h5>
            <ul class='list-group '>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>Eseménynaptár</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>Elhelyezkedés</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>Látnivalók, nevezetességek</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>Strandfürdő</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>Szálláshelyek</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='card' style='width: 18rem;'>
          <div class='card-body'>
            <h5 class='card-title'>Hirdetmények</h5>
            <ul class='list-group '>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>Térfigyelő rendszer</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>WIFI pontok</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>Beruházások</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>Pályázatok</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>Közérdekű információk</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='col-lg-2 col-md-4 p-1'>
        <!-- Gyorslinkek -->
        <div class='card' style='width: 18rem;'>
          <div class='card-body'>
            <h5 class='card-title'>Gyorslinkek</h5>
            <ul class='list-group '>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>A Polgármesteri Hivatal ügyfélfogadása</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>Rendelettár</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>Képviselő-testület</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>A Jász-Nagykun-Szolnok Megyei Kormányhivatal Járási Hivatala</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>Háziorvosok, fogorvosok rendelési ideje</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='col-lg-2 col-md-4 p-1'>
        <!-- Hírdetmények -->
        <div class='card' style='width: 18rem;'>
          <div class='card-body'>
            <h5 class='card-title'>Hirdetmények</h5>
            <ul class='list-group '>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>Térfigyelő rendszer</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>WIFI pontok</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>Beruházások</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>Pályázatok</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='card-link'>Közérdekű információk</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- End of first row-->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using only One Row :

```
<div class="container-fluid"> 
    <div class="row"> <!-- Welcome text  -->
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <p class="h1 text-center p-2">Üdvözöljük Városunk weboldalán!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row"> <!--Only One row-->
    
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 p-1"> <!-- Slider -->
        </div>
        
        <div class="row col-lg-6">
        
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 p-1"> <!-- Turizmus -->
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 p-1"> <!-- Gyorslinkek -->
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 p-1"> <!-- Hírdetmények -->
            </div> 
            
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 p-1"> <!-- Hírdetmények -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- End of therow-->
</div>
```